# Getting unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I want to display my wordpress blog posts as a list using jQuery mobile and JSON API but when I execute the program I am getting:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div class="entry">undefined
>   ...){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return"input"===t&&"button"===e.type||"button"=...

This is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
    Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <script src="css/style.css"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="blog" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" class="sys_hd" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_header" >
        <h1>Sysads Posts</h1>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-theme="c" data-role="content" id="postlist"> </div><!-- content -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-id="sys_footer" >
                    <div data-role="navbar" >
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#blog" class="sys_ft">Disclaimer</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar --> 
        </div><!-- footer --> 
    </div><!-- page -->
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
/**
 * @author Admin
 */
$(document).ready((function(){
     url = 'http://hopexxx.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function(xml){
            postlist = xml.responseData.feed.entries;
            console.log(postlist);
            $.each(postlist, function(data) {
                $('#postlist').append($('div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>'));
            });
        }
    });
}));
```

Comment: You forgot to open the tag :`$('div` should be `$('<div'`

Comment: might want to `console.log` out your `data` object too as `data.title` seems to be undefined.

Comment: silly me. you are correct, I am getting undefined. When i console log, i see the results: [Object { title="They didn’t Bow; They didn’t Burn", link="http://

What am i doing wrong at this stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `$('div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>')` is jQuery expresion that tries to find elements matching the expresion, but from the context you are trying to add html, not elements:

```
$.each(postlist, function(idx, data) {
    $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>');
});
```

And yes, as Damien wrote, the html was also broken.

Comment: Then the data variable is not what you think it is. Try console.log(data)

Comment: when I add console.log(data), I get just numbers 0 to 10 but when I use console.log(postlist) I get all the posts but still unable to dislay the result on my content page

Comment: That's because each function's first parameter is the index :) Should be function(idx, data)...

Comment: you such a genious, forgot that also. I am still new to javascipt

Comment: will post another question when i need more help. Thanks all

Comment: Final code:

$.each(postlist, function(i, data) {
             $('#postlist').append('<div class="entry">' + data.title + '</div>');
             console.log(data);